# Parsing #ifdef in C# with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to parse `#ifdef` declrations in H files with `Regex`.

Input example:

```
#ifdef D_MAIN /* CMNTS */
  #define EXT_D
  some code
#else /* CMNTS */
  #define EXT_D extern 
  some code
#endif /* CMNTS */
```

So far I've this expression:

```
\#ifdef\s+(\S*)[^\n]*
([^(.*)]*)
\#else\s+(\S*)[^\n]*
([^(.*)]*)
\#endif
```

I want to get a list of definitions , each def should take: def name(`D_MAIN`), the code inside the `#ifdef` statement and the code inside the `#else` stmnt.

I'm trying to make the `#else` part to be optional  with `?` but not succeed, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: side remark: This approach wont work with nested #ifdef statements :)

Comment: remark2: is there a reason for omitting \n matching after #else and #endif ? Moreover, what is your expression including the "?" isnt (\#endif)? working ?

Comment: You have to have the `#else` declaration in the `?` as well, eg. something like `(\#else([(.*)]*))?`. You probably want to use named captures if you want to get any meaningful data out of it, though.

Comment: Remark 3: What's that `[^(.*)]` supposed to do? I'm affraid it might be doing something you don't want it to :)

Comment: Hi, @Luaan I've tried this line, its not working as I expected, the `[^(.*)]` suppose to parse the code between the `#if` and the `#else`

Comment: The thing is, `[^(.*)]` says "any character that isn't `(`, `.`, `*` or `)`, which is obviously wrong (unless you're working with some very specific code pattern).

Comment: ok than , so what do you suggest ? `(.*)` not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `ifdef` block needs to be [non-greedy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Greedy), otherwise the fact that the `else` block is optional would allow it to capture everything up to `#endif`.

Second, `.*` will not accept multiple lines by default. You need to enable the [single-line option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline).

This pattern works with your input:

```
\#ifdef\s+(\S*)[^\n]*
(.*?)
(?:\s*\#else[^\n]*
(.*)
)?\s*\#endif
```